# HTML giving an issue when I try to make a color changing text CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a code where a text continuously changes color, it works but for some reason it gives me an arrow and I don't understand why
here is the CSS code

```
.colorchange {
  font-family: futura;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: colorchange 5s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colorchange {
  0% {
    color: blue;
  }
  10% {
    color: #8e44ad;
  }
  20% {
    color: #1abc9c;
  }
  30% {
    color: #d35400;
  }
  40% {
    color: blue;
  }
  50% {
    color: #34495e;
  }
  60% {
    color: blue;
  }
  70% {
    color: #2980b9;
  }
  80% {
    color: #f1c40f;
  }
  90% {
    color: #2980b9;
  }
  100% {
    color: pink;
  }
}
```

and this is the HTML code its effecting:

```
<h1 class="centered colorchange">
    <span>hello</span>
</h1>
```

the error says:

> Always define standard rule '@keyframes' when defining keyframes.
>
> Also define the standard property 'animation' for compatibility

it gives this error for some reason even though it works properly could someone tell my why it says this error

Comment: Because `@-webkit-keyframes ` is outdated . /you only need `@keyframes` Ditto `animation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a warning to use `@keyframes` instead of `@-webkit-keyframes`. The [-webkit-animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-animation) feature is non-standard.

```css
.colorchange {
  font-family: futura;
  font-style: italic;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: #313131;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: colorchange 5s infinite alternate;
}

/* Used "@keyframes" instead of "@-webkit-keyframes". */
@keyframes colorchange {
  0%   { color: blue; }
  10%  { color: #8e44ad; }
  20%  { color: #1abc9c; }
  30%  { color: #d35400; }
  40%  { color: blue; }
  50%  { color: #34495e; }
  60%  { color: blue; }
  70%  { color: #2980b9; }
  80%  { color: #f1c40f; }
  90%  { color: #2980b9; }
  100% { color: pink; }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="centered colorchange">
    <span>hello</span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace @-webkit-keyframes colorchange by @keyframes
and -webkit-animation by animation